# How to keep showing (In App) Update Screen if user closes it or presses Back press in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using the in-app update in my compose project, and the problem I came across is that if the user presses the close button, the update screen will disappear, or if they press the back button, it will remove the update screen, and the only time it shows again is if they leave or close the app and return to it.

Comment: can you share some more detail like code or screenshots?